# Unable to echo the real value of a variable

Tags: php, strlen

Iam given the following variable: **%4$s** that outputs the text "**a test**" in the code.

I am trying to `echo strlen('%4$s');` but it always returns **4** , while adding it as `echo strlen("%4$s");` is not returning again the real value (2), which in my opinion means that for some reason, is uses the number of the variable.

My primary scope is to check if **%4$s** contains two or more words or to count the characters of a returned string. 
At this time, **%4$s** , returns '**a test**' in my HTML, so I m expecting an echo of **%4$s** to return '**a test**' in PHP and a **strlen** of **%4$s** to return number **6**

Comment: Looking at the description of the **`variables`** tag that you used: *`THIS IS AMBIGUOUS; USE SPECIFIC-LANGUAGE TAGS WHENEVER APPLICABLE.`* <- not my capitalization. Please [Edit] the question and do what it suggests. Also, have you tried `echo strlen(%4$s)` (without any quotes)?

Comment: @PeterB edited - thanks. echoing without quotes returns a syntax error for unexpected %

Comment: Your edit (just a tag removed) does not make it any clearer. If this is about the language C or C++, then tag it `c` or `c++`, or whatever applies - doing so will increase your audience (people looking for those tags will see it) and that increases your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Clarified that its pure PHP

Comment: @JohnnyBratsoni What are you talking about? What is `%4$s` and why do you expect it to be `a test` especially if you put it into strlen??? `%4$2` are 4 characters, thus you get 4

Comment: 1) `strlen` is not what you want to check if it has more than 1 word. 2) How is `%4$s` a var - not seen any variable ever declared this way. strlen is seeing it as a string - not as a variable 3) strlen - string length. Your expected value is wrong .

Comment: I am getting the %4$s from this array : pastebin.com/X4JQjBkE - My code has %4$s , %8$s , %12$s , %14$s - they are all coming from this array check.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a string format suitable for something like [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) or [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) and you are wanting to know the length of the 4th entered value.

Sample code:

```
$format = '%4$s';
$val1 = 'one';
$val2 = 'two';
$val3 = 'three';
$val4 = 'a test';
echo sprintf($format,$val1,$val2,$val3,$val4);
```

Which will display:

```
a test
```

And you want to know the length of that 4th value. Instead of `strlen('%4$s')`, you should be doing `strlen($val4)`, for example:

```
echo strlen($val4);
```

Which will show:

```
6
```

A full example would be:

```
$format = '%5$d is the strlen of "%4$s"';
$val1 = 'one';
$val2 = 'two';
$val3 = 'three';
$val4 = 'a test';
echo sprintf($format,$val1,$val2,$val3,$val4,strlen($val4));
```

Which will display:

> 6 is the strlen of "a test"

**Edit:** It is still not very clear what you are doing even after looking at the pastebin link you posted. That said, the following is a guess that works. It uses the [`vsprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) method:

```
$format = '%6$s is the strlen of "%4$s"';
$retArr[0] = array('post_id' => 'one',
            'icon' => 'two',
            'title' => 'three',
            'permalink' => 'a test',
            'image' => '/path/to/img.png');
$retArr[0]['len'] = strlen($retArr[0]['permalink']);
echo vsprintf($format,$retArr[0]);
```

And still outputs:

> 6 is the strlen of "a test"

Comment: @JohnnyBratsoni : Made a change, but it is really not clear where and how you are using the code. You should also update the question with the extra information for others to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Referring : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

```
Double quoted ¶
If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret the following escape sequences for special characters:

$
```

is an escape character in php and if you don't escape it correctly using `"\"` like `"\$s"` `"s"` will be treated as a variable `"$s"`.
Hence you are getting count as `2`

Comment: I tried echoing %4\$s but its not returning the expected text. I want to count the characters of a returned string. %4$s , returns 'a test' in my html, so I m expecting an echo of %4\$s to return 'a test' in php and a strlen of %4\$s to have the number of 6

Answer (score 0):

strlen returns the amount of letters in a string so that's why you are getting the number 4 instead of your string.

try : `'%4'.$s`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, echo('%4'.$s) still returned %4

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that will count string length (by char) and do a word count.

Note: This isn't a copy-and-paste solution, so you will need to change your code to fit.

You can get the word count easily by doing the generic rule that words are separated by spaces. Here's where a PHP function called [explode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) comes in. We can use that combined with [count()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to get the word count:

```
$foo = 'a test';

$wordCount = count(explode(' ', $foo));
$strLength = strlen($foo);

echo $wordCount; # will output 2
echo $strLength; # will output 6
```

I've seen your pastebin for your array data, you can just loop through the array to get the individual values or use `$array[$key]` to specify a certain value to target.